# uitableview commitEditingStyle crashes when dismissing view

Tags: swift, uitableview

**The solution for this bug:**

I removed the method bellow from my implementation. Although it works I am still keen to find why the method bellow did not work with my implementation when the documentation mention they are built to work together.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

**The original question:**

The following code works to delete rows and also to delete records on coredata. So far so good. But I get a crash **ONLY** when I try to leave the view that contains this tableview view **while the slide to delete button is active** for one of the rows.

If the slide to delete button is not active and I try to dismiss the view it works fine and no crashes.

I get the following error.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { error thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

I commented everything inside the method, but even with no code inside it still crashes.

Am I missing something in the implementation of the method or not using it correctly?

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if(editingStyle == .Delete ) {

//            let concreteItemToDelete = concreteItems[indexPath.row]
//            managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(concreteItemToDelete)
//            self.fetchLog()
//            mainTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }
    }
```

[image]

Debug console:

[image]

Comment: What message do you see in the debug console when you crash?

Comment: Just added the debug console image

Comment: Try adding `All Exception` breakpoint.

Comment: I got it to work. Please see the end of my question. Still not sure why didn't work on my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the previous View has been desallocated from memory when you try to dismiss. Looks like the garbage collector cleans the previous view when you slide to delete.

I had a similar problem, with the same EX_BAD_ACESS and no stack trace. In my case, everthing was working until the third time I performed the dismiss. I`m using a PageManu, and performing the segue from a tableview in a view inside called controller2.

I added this in the 'main' ViewController (Who adds the other views to PageMenu) and worked well:

```
self.addChildViewController(controller1)
self.addChildViewController(controller2)
```

Controller 1 and 2 are the views that I slide on pagemenu. Now, seems that the garbage collector don`t desallocate the view when I come back.